# VS for Mac - can't run XF.iOS on Simulator or registered Device

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

The solution compiles ok; runs on the Android Emulator. Created a new project and same issues.

When I click the run button, it hangs on Deploying to Device. There are no entries in the "Deploying to Device" log window. The Simulator doesn't even start. I created an AppID in the AAPL dev portal with the reverse domain.
This is the 3rd app I tried to build - first worked ok w/o issues. The next two, not so much.

**Are there any logs I can look into?**

- macOS Sierra 10.12.2 (16C68)

  - VS Version Preview 2 (7.0 build 560)
- Xamarin.iOS

  - Version: 10.3.1.7 (Visual Studio Enterprise)
  - Hash: 8b53676
  - Branch: cycle8-xi
  - Build date: 2016-12-18 12:23:27-0500
- Xamarin.Android

  - Version: 7.0.2.42 (Visual Studio Enterprise)
- Android SDK: /Users/martenliebster/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx

  - Supported Android versions:
  - 6.0 (API level 23)
  - 7.0 (API level 24)
  - SDK Tools Version: 25.2.5
  - SDK Platform Tools Version: 25.0.3
  - SDK Build Tools Version: 25.0.2

At the end of the Build output there's this:

```
Target _CollectFrameworks:
CollectFrameworks Task
AppBundlePath: bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/QV.iOS.app/
No Frameworks directory found.
Done building project "/Users/martenliebster/Projects/QV/iOS/QV.iOS.csproj".
Build succeeded.
0 Warning(s)
0 Error(s)
```

Added: If bring up the app that used to work, and try to run the app in the simulator - it builds and then nothing. The button goes right back to the Arrow. No errors, no popups, no nothing.

Comment: I would look at the device logs to see what is up. There is a Device log window that you can open and then select a connected iOS device to see its logs in real time. There is often a good actionable error message in the device log for issues such as this. (Note this is only for actual device, for simulators I believe the device logs go to the Mac system logs which can be viewed in the Console app).

Comment: Thanks - but all the logs are empty -  Device, Deploying Device, App Output, Packaging, Errors; and the status bar is stuck on "Deploying to device". Where would I find the "Console app"? (I'm relatively new to the "it just works" Mac world)

Comment: I found the logs (in the simulator, debug menu); when I hit play and the simulator isn't running, it just goes back to the play state and the simulator doesn't start. If I manually start up the simulator and after it settles I hit start, the log has no new entries. I've even tried to use the Hanselman.Forms app, just in case I had something goofy in my app.

Comment: What version of XCode are you on? If not the latest, I would recommend updating XCode. Otherwise file a bug report. I missed the part where you said the simulator was not even launching, which makes my suggestion to check the device logs irrelevant, sorry about that.  Please report any problems you encounter with the Visual Studio for Mac Preview using the Help > Report a Problem menu.

Comment: @jgoldberger Thanks - Xcode Version 8.2.1 (8C1002).

Comment: Issue reported. Lemme know what ever I can do to help.

Comment: Can you share the bug report link so I can look into this further?

Comment: @jgoldberger - I never got a bug report response; I did the "Help > Report a Problem" and the dialog went away when I clicked the button. Should I have received an email or something?

Comment: Oh, odd, as you know VS for Mac is still in Preview. I was just following our guide for VS for Mac on how to report a problem. https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/vs-mac/preview/vs-mac-preview1/#Feedback ... Perhaps that is not working correctly yet. I am going to install VS for Mac and see what happens on my end. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @jgoldberger is there a place (dialog in VS or webpage) to view the active support issues, so I could bring up the details you're looking for? Essentially I rewrote what I have in this thread - the dialog asked about telemetry, so I figured that the process gathered various system infos and submitted with the report.

Comment: I think the Xamarin Forums, where you also posted this issue, is the better venue for problems with an IDE as SO is more about coding issues/questions. I will post further response there. (Link: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/86506/vs-for-mac-cant-run-xf-ios-on-simulator-or-registered-device#latest )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by:

1) Updated VS for Mac to preview 3 and 2) going to Xamarin Studio and getting platform updates through that (as VS didn't update iOS or Droid).

Comment: Note that Xamarin Sutdio needs to be updated to the Alpha channel at this time.